# Downloading files in python not working properly

Tags: python

I have a script to download the files from a file full of links(one link per line). To do the same, I made a for loop which would download every link in each line, but unexpectedly it's only downloading the last link in the file. Here is my code for the python script that I tried:

```
import time
import requests
import requests
import os.path

with open('Links.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as link_file:
    for link in link_file:
                def download_url(_url):
                    print("downloading: ", _url)
                    file_name_start_pos = _url.rfind("/") + 1
                    file_name = _url[file_name_start_pos:]
                    r = requests.get(_url, stream=True)
                    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
                        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
                            for data in r:
                                f.write(data)
                    return os.path.exists(file_name)
                download_url(link)
```

Please help with my script, any alternatives would be fine as well.

Comment: `if len(link) > 3: continue` check if emtpy line first

Comment: in my worstation with python 3.8 its running fine your script is downloading all files what do you expect else? can you share link samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to strip the newlines from each of the lines. If you don't, you'll end up calling `google.com\n` and get back a HTTP 400. The last site in the file succeeds because it doesn't have a newline.

```py
def download_url(_url):
    _url = _url.strip()
```